# Bootstrapping confidence intervals in R: BCa method and prescribed resamples

Tags: r, confidence-interval, statistics-bootstrap

I would like to estimate confidence intervals in R using the BCa method (correcting for bias and asymmetric boot distribution). However, my resamples are not ''standard resamples'' but something more complicated and thus I would like to generate them separately and subsequently apply a BCa algorithm. As far as I see there exist the function "BootBCa" as well as the ''boot'' package in R. However, in both cases resamples are automatically generated. Is there any way in R to firstly prescribe resamples and secondly apply a BCa method?

Thanks,

Moritz

Comment: Structure your resample output so that it can be passed to `boot.ci` ?

Comment: Thank you user20650, that works fine.