# BCa confidence interval using pre-bootstrapped data

Tags: r, confidence-interval, statistics-bootstrap

I want to calculate a BCa confidence interval using the function *boot.ci* in the *boot* package. I do already have bootstrap replicates (**not** calculated using the *boot* function provided by the package). 
To calculate a BCa confidence interval, it should be sufficient to pass the bootstrap replicates together with the observed statistic to the *boot.ci* function (parameters *t* and *t0*). However, technically, *boot.ci* requires an object of class "*boot*" to be the first argument in the function call. It seems that it is possible to pass just some arbitrary *boot* object to the function, as long as the number of replicates (*R*) is appropiate. However, calculating a faked boot object which is actually not needed seems a little bit inefficient. Another possibility is to construct a faked boot object from scratch, as discussed here ([How can I use pre bootstrapped data to obtain a BCa confidence interval?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41786693/how-can-i-use-pre-bootstrapped-data-to-obtain-a-bca-confidence-interval)) and here ([Bootstrapping confidence intervals in R: BCa method and prescribed resamples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31314056/bootstrapping-confidence-intervals-in-r-bca-method-and-prescribed-resamples)). This avoids at least wasting runtime, but is still not very elegant. I wonder if there is anybody who knows an even smarter solution (e.g. modified code for *boot.ci*). Thanks a lot!

Comment: I don't fully understand what you mean - actual sample code would be better - but maybe package simpleboot with one.boot could help?

Comment: Meanwhile, I found the package "wBoot" which offers the function "boot.two.bca". Seems to yield similar results (with quite different code).